# Populating several listboxes on a winform from multidimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, listbox

I have the following code that successfully splits filepaths into the constituent folders and filename:

```
var allfiles = FileLister.GetListOfFiles(_path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

List<string[]> n = new List<string[]>();

foreach (var line in allfiles)
{
    var str = line.Split(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);
    n.Add(str);
}
```

The result (n) is a two dimensional array that looks like this:

[image: result of splitting filepath]

Given a "node" position e.g n[0] as seen in the image, I need to transfer the data in n[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wgmn.jpg) to n[0][6] to a winform that has five listboxes as shown:

[image]

So my final desired result is that listbox1 will have all the data in n[0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wgmn.jpg), n[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wgmn.jpg), n[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wgmn.jpg) and so on. Listbox two will have all the data in n[0][3], n[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo5ee.jpg)[3], n[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wgmn.jpg)[3] and so on..

Im very new to C# and just dont know how to code this. I would appreciate some help please or even suggestions on an alternative way to do this.

cheers

Comment: You can loop over the items and in each loop loop over the array. 
Assuming there will always be th same number of path parts. 
Put your listboxes in a List<ListBox> so you can reference it by an index.  This will also help if you create the listboxes dynaically as I would suggest..
To make sure you have enough listboxes use:

    `int nmax = n.Select(x => x.Cast<string[]>().Count()).Max();`

Comment: Thanks @TaW i will try this out !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some sample code to point you in the right direction. Agree with Taw's comments regarding having enough listboxes depending on the depth of your filesystem. This example assumes that you don't have a folder structure that goes deeper than 4 levels:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // list of ListBoxes - makes it easy to work out which one to add filepath item to
    List<ListBox> boxes = new List<ListBox>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        boxes.Add(this.listBox1);
        boxes.Add(this.listBox2);
        boxes.Add(this.listBox3);
        boxes.Add(this.listBox4);
        // populate the ListBoxes
        populateLists();
    }

    public void populateLists()
    {
        // simulate getting data from filesystem
        List<string[]> n = new List<string[]>();
        n.Add(new string[] { "C:", "foo1", "bar1", "test1.txt" });
        n.Add(new string[] { "D:", "foo2", "bar2", "test2.txt" });
        n.Add(new string[] { "E:", "foo3", "bar3", "test3.txt" });
        n.Add(new string[] { "F:", "foo4", "bar4", "test4.txt" });
        n.Add(new string[] { "G:", "foo5", "bar5", "test5.txt" });

        // loop through list items
        for (var i = 0; i < n.Count; i++)
        {
        // loop through arrays for each list item
            for (var j = 0; j < n[i].Length; j++)
            {
            boxes[j].Items.Add(n[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this really helped ! and yes at the moment the subfolder depth is fixed, but i want to make this dynamic in my next trial. cheers !